# Cartoon from the 70s or 80s with different coloured monsters that had powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Unfortunately I do not have a lot to give in terms of details. It is vague memories from when I was a kid.

I used to watch this cartoon in the late 80s or early 90s. I was very young and can’t remember much. This is what I can remember:

It had monster characters. They were different colours and shapes and each one had a different kind of power.

The one power I remember was this one character could spit out sticky tape, and use it to mend things.

I cannot remember if there were human characters or not. It was in English and it’s colour palette was bright and colourful.